# Audio and video... and tango?

Tags: etymology, modern-life, conjugation, english

**Audio** and **video** are two ([apparently XX-century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=audio%2C+video&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caudio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvideo%3B%2Cc0)) concepts.

Both take the same form as **1st-person sing., present tense Latin verbs**. Wiktionary articles for the English words ([audio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/audio), [video](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/video)) assert that their etymology actually is that of those verbal forms, and so does (apparently) Etymonline ([audio](https://www.etymonline.com/word/audio#etymonline_v_18930), [video](https://www.etymonline.com/word/video#etymonline_v_7777)).

I could be wrong, but I can't think of any older word derived from Latin in this way. Instead, it reminds me of some initial translation attempts by people with little inflectional background, looking for dictionary entries for verbs, assuming that the verb *is* its 1st-pers. s. form.

This sounds wrong to me, as I can't see a reason why someone could want to name something an *I see* recorder, or an *I hear* wave.

**Question:** Is there a reason to draw these words from that verbal forms in specific? Or is it just bad Latin from an era when Latin is no longer the language of science?

**Bonus fact:** I thought the same applied to [tango](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tango), but it seems to have a different origin.

Comment: What about studio? Would it come from _studeo_ or from _studium_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary indicates that the O in *audio, video* and *radio* comes from the O found in Greek compounds, which was used in scientific vocabulary built from Latin and Greek roots: e.g. *audiology* or *radiometer.*

Note that the Etymonline entry for *audio* actually seems to say the same thing:

> abstracted from **word-forming element** **audio-** (q.v.), which is from Latin *audire* "to hear"

Comment: Hmm, so the OED suggests it's mixed etymology (Latin-Greek), just as _television_, which is arguably bad, but not as bad as I thought. But then again, is Etymonline not to be trusted?

Comment: OED is a serious scholarly work. Etymonline is a paste job.

Comment: @fdb I don't doubt OED either. I just wondered whether the 1st. p. s. could still be a valid competing theory

Comment: @Rafael no, the 1SG hypothesis cannot be competing or valid.